# Set timestamp using kafkacat when producing

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I want to be able to transmit messages to kafka using kafkacat but also set the timestamp of the messages. But it seems like this is not possible. Is this true or is there something that I am missing. I can't seem to find a full kafkacat reference documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to specify timestamps when producing, this is something we'll implement when adding the JSON-based producer allowing a user to pass message metadata fields, such as headers and timestamps.